# How to add subtract two signals?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

The question is:

> Two signals have to be subtracted from each other. You want to have a very high input resistance and an overall transfer functiON of Uout=2*(U1-U2).
>
> Draw a suitable circuit diagram. The resistors of your circuit have tolerance of +-10%, futhermore U2=0, U1=5V. Calculate and plot the output signals.

Answer: I got the diagram from my friend.

[image: schematic]

That's the diagram that he senT me, But I don't understand. I got why he used the first opamp but what is it with the second? Can somebody explain me?

Comment: Also, this circuit does not have "very high input resistance". The input resistance is just R1 and R2. Probably this question wants you to know about an [instrumentation amplifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_amplifier).

Comment: Furthermore, the question stipulates that the input voltages are constant, thus \$U_{out}=2(U_1-U_2) = 2(5V-0V) = 10V\$. You don't need any amplifiers at all, just a voltage source.

Comment: Yes you may be right. But I think I have to solve the diagram to get Uout=2*(U1-U2) and after that do whatever you have said it to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *second* op amp inverts the output of the first.  It's not really needed; rather you should swap U1 and U2.

For high input impedance, try this one:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcDmEy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the R's have all the same value, you should get a gain of 2.

Answer (score 3):

The circuit you have does not seem to be a very good one as the input impedance may be too low

A better circuit would be:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjm44w.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here OA1 and OA2 are wired as unity gain followers so provide very high input impedance. O3 is wired as a differential amplifier with gain 2.

Answer (score -1):

Your friend's solution is overly complicated.  This circuit meets all the specifications as you stated them:

[image]

It has infinite input impedance, and no tolerance issues due to resistors being only 10%.

Comment: To those who are suddenly downvoting this: Apparently the question was edited after I wrote this answer. Note the time of my answer and the times of the edits. This is a correct answer to the question *as asked at the time*.

Comment: "Suddenly", perhaps, because I wasn't here in January and have only just now run across this thread, but "those"???  I see only one downvote, it's mine, and I invoked it because of the flippant nature of your cryptic answer, apparently designed not as a sincere effort to help the querent, but as a means of self-aggrandizement a la: "See how smart I am."  As far as the editing timeline goes, I see neither its relevance nor a compelling reason for the form of your answer, when a circuit diagram/schematic would have been much more illustrative of your "concept".

Comment: @EMFi: You need to learn how this site works. You may not have enough rep to see individual votes or the edit history. This question is at +2,-3, with all the downvotes happening in the last few days when it got bumped to the top by Clabacchio's edit of the question. The original question asked how to do Out=2(U1-U2) and then stipulated that U2=0 V and U1=5 V. A fixed output of 10 V is therefore a legitimate answer. This was also intended to point out how a poorly written spec can beget a correct but unintended solution, which is a valuable lesson.

Comment: What I'm learning about this site is that some of its high-rep denizens - who gathered the low-hanging fruit, BTW - seem to be  more intent in saving face than they are in truthfully admitting to error; technical or otherwise.  In a different, but related vein, your answer still doesn't comply with the OP's request for an explanation, nor does it delve into the meat and potatoes of the schematic - which is what he specifically asked for - but rather seems designed to "justifiably" ignore his wishes by trivializing him while exalting yourself.